# Using discord.py I have made a blacklist that filters certain words, it seems to be deleting user images and I cannot find out why

Tags: python, discord

Code:

```
#W A T C H E R
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  # L O G G I N G
  username = message.author.display_name
  msg = message.content
  with open('blacklist.txt', 'r') as f:
    blacklist = f.read()
    if message.author.bot:
      return
    elif msg.lower() in blacklist:
      await message.delete()
    else:
      await bot.process_commands(message)
```

That code just checks if user input is in the blacklist word list and based on that deletes or keeps the message. But the bot keeps deleting images that users post instead of just words that are listed in the blacklist category.

Literally auto-deletes user images in any channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they send an image they most likely dont send any content so `msg.lower()` is an empty string and an empty string is always inside any string

```py
>>> "" in "some words here"
True
```

consider making it check if the content is inside a list of blacklisted words instead of a single string, for example

```py
if msg.lower() in blacklist.split():
    ...
```

`str.split` returns a list of words in the string: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

or even better loop over `blacklist.split()` and check if any of the words are inside `msg.lower()`, for example `if any(word for word in blacklist.split() if word in msg.lower())`.

Comment: This worked but can you explain in greater detail what the ``.split()`` does.

Comment: .split() splits a string into an array based on a separating character, with the default being space. For example, `"some words here".split()` is `["some", "words", "here"]`

Comment: Ah ok I get it so without split let's say the blacklisted word is 'jello' someone can get away with saying 'hi this is jello', but with the ``.split()`` the bot can catch on.

Comment: Sort of! Right now you're checking your message against the entire string of the blacklist. Even if a single word in the message is in the blacklist, `msg in blacklist` checks if _the entire message text_ is in the blacklist, which in most cases it isn't. On the other hand, when the message is an empty string, it will always say it is in the blacklist since `"" in str` is always true. `.split()` will help you check if each word in the blacklist individually is in your message.

Comment: You may also run into the opposite problem; if you check for `word in msg.lower()`, you'll end up censoring parts of words, so the name Cassandra or the word "pass" might be blocked because they contain a forbidden word.