# How do I store server preferences in a database that is easy to use?

Tags: python, database, discord, discord.py

I am trying to figure out a good way to use a database to store server preferences.
If that doesn't make sense I'll try to explain:

By server preference I mean command & event customization, so if they want to add banned words to their server it will add it to a database.

Using the database, it will get the banned words list from it.

Using on_message(message), it will get the server id, and check what banned words are in the database.

Example:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  #code
  Possibly something like:
  if message.guild.id in database:
    if message.content in database:
      await message.delete()
      await message.channel.send(f"Do not say that {message.author.mention}!"
```

I have tried to find videos online but cannot find a good one, and nothing have been helpful.

If anyone knows how to do this please send documents, tutorial videos, tutorial websites, or anything you have. Thanks, and have a great day!

Comment: I can also use JSON files if that makes it easier.

Comment: Whenever I see a question like this, I always recommend to break it up into parts. There may be no videos on how to do specifically what you're looking for, but what are the steps? For me #1 would be to figure out how to store things in a database, #2: how to load variables from a database, and #3: how to apply those variables to do what you want (i.e. the same question you're looking for, but without the database).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002481/using-discord-py-i-have-made-a-blacklist-that-filters-certain-words-it-seems-to might help. You can change reading the .txt file into creating a command for banning words and then dumping those words into a .json file with the guild id.

Answer (score 0):

I think a very simple way to do this is use something like [TinyDB](https://pypi.org/project/tinydb/).

[Link](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to docs.

Basically all you have to do is just have a local JSON file.

Then in your case you have records where you save the records.

So when someone first saves their banned words you save something in TinyDB like so.

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query

def save_banned_words(server_id, new_words):
    db = TinyDB('/path/to/db.json')

    #check to see if server data already saved
    Server = Query()
    #doing a query 
    existing_server_data = db.search(Server.server_id == server_id)
    if len(existing_server_data) > 0:
        #get the current list of words saved and combine with new words
        saved_words = existing_server_data[0]['banned_words']
        combined_words_list = saved_words + new_words

        #update the words in database
        db.update({'banned_words': combined_words_list}, Server.server_id == server_id)
    
    #if server data doesn't exist already we just create new record with new words
    else:
         db.insert({'server_id': server_id, 'banned_words': new_words})
```

Now that you can save words, we have to query for if a word is banned or not for when users write messages in the chat.

Using the function you already provided in your question:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  db = TinyDB('/path/to/db.json')
  #Creating our query to check for banned words
  Server = Query()
  #first check there is actually banned word data
  server_data = db.search(Server.server_id == message.guild.id)
  if len(server_data) > 0:
    #taking first element of server data because its stored like such [{}]
    server_data = server_data[0]
    #loop through all banned words saved
    for banned_word in server_data['banned_words']:
         #if banned word found in message delete it
         if banned_word in message.content:
           await message.delete()
           await message.channel.send(f"Do not say that {message.author.mention}!"
```

Hopefully this puts you on the right track :D.